# Node.js - Firebase-admin fails while installing

Tags: node.js, firebase, server, shared-hosting, firebase-admin

I get an error when I try to install Firebase-admin sdk. I do not receive any errors while working on my own computer but I could not set up a shared hosting.

**MY CONNECTION CODE:**

```
    var serviceAccount = require("/home/maksuboi/firebase_admin_connection.json");
    admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://********.firebaseio.com'
    });
```

**ERROR**

```
 const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
                            ^

Error: error:02016002:system library:stat:No such file or directory
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:86:29)
    at Object.sign (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jwa/index.js:152:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:186:16)
    at ServiceAccountCredential.createAuthJwt_ (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:101:20)
    at ServiceAccountCredential.getAccessToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:75:26)
    at FirebaseAppInternals.getToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:64:73)
    at AuthTokenProvider.getToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9231:27)
    at PersistentConnection.establishConnection_ (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12133:18)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/app/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12035:19) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error',
    'error:0E07B075:configuration file routines:ssl_module_init:ssl command section empty'
  ],
  library: 'system library',
  function: 'stat',
  reason: 'No such file or directory',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_SYS_NO_SUCH_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY'
}
```

Comment: Looks like a broken `crypto` module in your Node.js installation. The error is thrown by Node.js at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.x/lib/internal/crypto/sig.js#L84. Possibly a bug in your Node.js version on Windows, or you need to do some additional Windows-specific set up to get the crypto working correctly.

Comment: I dont use windows. I use shared hosting on linux. What exactly do I have to do?

Comment: Then why is your service account a windows path: `require("C:/server/firebase_admin_connection.json")`

Comment: I got the code from my windows computer. Everything works fine on Windows. 
But there is an error in linux.

Comment: I corrected my code.

Comment: Thanks. But this is still an issue with your environment. Probably a broken OpenSSL installation (I see some openssl errors in the output). Best to reach out to the people who are managing this environment, and let them know about the problem.